# sorting list for display with python or jquery for cherrypy page

Tags: jquery, python, sorting, tablesorter, cherrypy

I have a cherrypy project which has a webpage to display the results of a database query as a list of all the rows, sometimes 10,000+ rows. The database query returns a list with each item of the list being a tuple of all the columns from the query. I wanted to put some sort of default sort order to make the pagination I have added more usable. But, as I have tested adding the sort with python and jquery I have found limitations of both that I am unsure if I just don't know how to overcome them or if I should just use the other method.

With my python method I use the sorted() function and the itemgetter operator, but I find that with a mix of letters of varying case and numbers in the column used for sorting it uses ASCIIbetical order [0, 10, 2, 20, A, C, Z, a, z]. This sort order is not ideal, but I have not been able to find a way yet to manipulate the sort to a different type. An example of the code I would use to sort is below

```
from operator import itemgetter
random_list = [('a', 'value'), ('b', 'value'), ('0', 'value'), ('8', 'value'), ('Z', 'value'), ('2', 'value'), ('A', 'value'), ('z', 'value'), ('100', 'value'), ('250', 'value'), ('20', 'value'), ('25', 'value'), ('10', 'value'), ('11', 'value'), ('c', 'value')]
sorted_results = sorted(random_list,key=itemgetter(0))
print sorted_results
[('0', 'value'), ('10', 'value'), ('100', 'value'), ('11', 'value'), ('2', 'value'), ('20', 'value'), ('25', 'value'), ('250', 'value'), ('8', 'value'), ('A', 'value'), ('Z', 'value'), ('a', 'value'), ('b', 'value'), ('c', 'value'), ('z', 'value')]
```

This method currently takes about 6-7 seconds less to load the page fully than the jquery method I will describe below.

For jquery sorting I have been trying out the tablesorter jquery plugin. I included the jquery.tablesorter.js file in my project and linked to it on my page. This method returns alphabetical order and I instead see a list order like [0, A, C, Z, a, z, 2, 10, 20] which is much better than the ASCIIbetical from my python method. This jquery method though does take much longer to sort the results and have a fully loaded/functional page.

Below is a snip of my jquery code linked to my html page with the table to be sorted with `id="data-table"`

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#data-table")
    .tablesorter({sortList: [[1,0],[0,0]]});
}
```

Is there a way to manipulate the quicker python method to instead sort how I would like, or are there methods I should look into for optimizing how the jquery works?

**EDIT**

randomir in the comments pointed me to the natsort module for python and it appears to be exactly the type of sorting I was looking for that is quicker than my jquery method. If anyone else has other suggestions, I am always open to optimization

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Python have a built in function for string natural sort?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836710/does-python-have-a-built-in-function-for-string-natural-sort)

Comment: Seems like [natsort](https://github.com/SethMMorton/natsort) is what you are looking for.

Comment: @randomir I thought this was distinct enough because I am trying to sort a list based on a value inside a tuple which is each item of the list. As well, I am using the itemgetter method, the methods described in your linked question did not appear to work for me when I was testing this as it could not get an item from inside the tuple to sort on. I will checkout natsort though now'

Comment: It works fine because tuples are sorted first by first item, then by second. Try: `from natsort import natsorted`, `natsorted(random_list)`. You'll get exactly what you need.

Comment: @randomir natsort appears to be exactly what I was looking for, thank you for pointing me in the right direction. What if I am trying to sort on say the 3rd or 4th item in a tuple for my much larger result sets? I am looking through the docs now but figured I would see if you knew

Comment: [`natsorted` is compatible with `sorted`](http://natsort.readthedocs.io/en/stable/natsorted.html#natsorted), similarly it accepts the `key` argument. So you would use `natsorted(data, key=itemgetter(3))`.

Comment: Any chance to change DB query to do sorting and pagination? Normally using Python it would be much more inefficient.